# I can't align Images horizontally

Tags: css

I can't seem to make my images align side by side, they just keep stacking on top of each other. I have only enough knowledge to fumble my way through with instructions and I'm stuck here.

HTML:

```
<div class='sticky-bar'>
    <div class='sticky-bar-inner'>
        <div>
            <a href='https://www.facebook.com/salvageinteriors' target='_blank'>
                <img src='img.png' /> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cant seem to get the rest of the code in here, but it just keeps repeating the above.

CSS:

```
.sticky-bar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
    left: 10px;
    margin: 9px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: fixed;
    width: 45px;
    z-index: 62;
}

.sticky-bar-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: left;
    width:90%;
}
```

Comment: how does it repeat? not sure I understood it.

Comment: I think u need the [holy grail solution](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use **float:left** property. It will use to align div's side by side and when the parent width is reached then , the images will align in next line.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='sticky-bar'>
    <div class='sticky-bar-inner'>
        <div class="inner-divs">
            <a href='https://www.facebook.com/salvageinteriors' target='_blank'>
                <img src='img.png' /> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

Set width for **.sticky-bar-inner** class

```
.sticky-bar-inner {
    padding: 20px 0;
    width:500px;
}
```

and set **float:left** property to inner image divs.

```
.inner-divs{
   float:left;
}
```